# What Android device manufacturers supply their devices with longer software update life cycles than Google supplies its Nexus and Pixel devices?

Tags: updates, manufacturers

Google's software update life cycle policy for Nexus and Pixel devices is that:
1. They "get Android version updates for at least 2 years from when the device became available on the Google Store. After 2 years, we can't guarantee additional updates."
2. They "get security patches for at least 3 years from when the device first became available, or at least 18 months from when the Google Store last sold the device, whichever is longer."
Source: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705?hl=en

Are there any manufacturers that give their devices longer life cycles than Google gives Nexus and Pixel devices when it comes to Android version updates, security patches, or both?

In addition, if possible, please tell me how rapidly these manufacturers provide Android version updates and/or monthly security updates, in comparison to how rapidly Google provides them to Nexus and Pixel devices.

Comment: No... At least not with any consistency or guarantee. Pixel/Nexus devices have the longest manufacturer's update life cycle.

Comment: Flagging as too broad after last edit.

Comment: If you're just looking for as many Android version/security updates (minus "from manufacturers"), better off buying known developer-friendly phones that has active 3rd-party development. Custom ROMs will always last longer than any sort of manufacturer support.

Comment: @acejavelin the reason for my last edit--where I added the part asking about update speed--is because responses that include information about update speed would help me narrow my choices down further. If others agree that that edit makes my question too broad (even though it technically is not part of my question, because it is an addendum to it, at the end of the question's details section, and not in the title) then I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone worth their salt is 2 and 3 for Security Patches, manufacturers with fewer phones and a greater concern for security (Blackberry) might extend the life cycle for the security but Android Version upgrades won't come if the next version is far enough away to let it slide (depending upon Devices in service vs. the idea of buying a new phone).

Once you're off Contract you can Root and Update yourself (cost the Mfg. nothing too) so there's little reason for them to support older Models IF people aren't going to complain (or make it a purchase consideration).

As for the second question: http://www.androidauthority.com/android-oem-update-speed-743073/ .

For Nougat:

LG: 78 days
Motorola: 88 days
HTC: 95 days
Sony: 99 days
Xiaomi: 126 days
OnePlus: 131 days
Samsung: 143 days
Huawei: Might get Nougat Q2 2017

Comment: "If the next version is far enough away to let it slide" --> Android version upgrades come once per year, so it sounds like you're saying that even with security-focused manufacturers, after the normal two-years is over, will skip the next version upgrade if it is far enough away during the following 365 days, offering it only to devices less than three years old? Did I interpret your answer correctly?

Comment: "If people aren't going to complain (or make it a purchase consideration)." --> For me, the speed with which manufacturers will provide updates--especially security updates--is the primary factor in my purchase decision. I do wonder, however, whether I am worrying too much about vulnerabilities not getting patched by third-party manufacturers as quickly as Google patches them, because some third-party manufacturers' devices might otherwise appeal to me.

Comment: 1.) It is usual to discontinue updates in this order: Version, UI, and finally Security. Version is the first to go because it's the most work (not just testing everything but each Carrier has to sign-off). UI will be kept 'the same' because they know what is best BUT if the UI gets an Upgrade that is not Hardware focused then it gets pushed to older Devices to keep the whole lineup amalgamated (and no involvement with either Android or Carriers) with security updates last to go so their Rep. is not tarnished. -- 2.) With Google Hardware and Software just one place. Buy from Carrier and Root.